# Protobuf - json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field of int32

Tags: json, go, protocol-buffers, unmarshalling

I am trying to unmarshall the contents of my json file and one of the attribute fields is this:

```
"sensor_node_id": 6,
```

Inside my .proto file I have:

```
message Attributes1 {
    // delete above attributes because too many and just want to show what I define here
    int32 sensor_node_id = 12;
    // deleted below remaining attributes
}

message Attributes {
    Attributes1 attributes = 1;
    string message = 2;
    string service = 3;
    string status = 4;
    repeated string tags = 5;
    string timestamp = 6;
}
```

and then when I generate my protobuf file I get this struct:

```
type Attributes1 struct {
    SensorNodeId     int32             `protobuf:"varint,12,opt,name=sensor_node_id,json=sensorNodeId,proto3" json:"sensor_node_id,omitempty"`

}
```

Then when I run my program I see this error:

```
2022/04/04 13:16:15 json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Attributes.data.attributes.attributes.sensor_node_id of type int32
```

Would anyone be kind enough to help with this problem. I spent a few hours googling how to resolve this and it seems not as simple as I thought.

I tried changing it to "string" after actually but then I get the error which goes along the lines of something like:

```
Cannot unmarshal a number into a string....
```

Comment: It sounds like there is another field called "sensor_node_id" in your JSON input that is a string. Maybe some problem with struct nesting? Can you show the complete JSON input?

Comment: oh my lord jesus you are right..... the json file i was working with is no bueno... I double checked and the field "sensor_node_id" which is just the id of my bluetooth sensor it was returning sometimes a number and sometimes a string...

Comment: Would there be a way to account for this in the code? @BurakSerdar

Comment: I am not aware of a way of doing it in proto. There is, in go json marshaling: use a custom type with unmarshaler.

Comment: The interesting thing is before I migrated to protobuff, I had this huge struct defined in my file and I used the type "json.Number" which seemed to have worked. However, json.Number is not a valid type when I use it in the .proto file